# Error in a custom sympy function when trying to print the squared function with latex

Tags: latex, sympy

I would like to write a custom SymPy Function with special latex output. A simplified function might look like the following:

```py
from sympy import Function, Symbol, latex

class TestClass(Function):
    def _latex(self, printer):
        m = self.args[0]
        _m = printer._print(m)
        return _m + '(x)'

S = Symbol('S')
latex(TestClass(S)**2)
```

However, this gives me the error

> TypeError: TestClass._latex() got an unexpected keyword argument 'exp'

Can someone please help me to understand what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TestClass` is a subclass of `Function`.

`TestClass(S)**2` is an instance of `Pow`. Let's look at the source code of the `LatexPrinter` class, specifically at the `_print_Pow` method:

```py
        if expr.base.is_Function:
            return self._print(expr.base, exp=self._print(expr.exp))
```

Under the hood, `self._print` checks if `expr.base` implements the `_latex` method. If it does (like in your test case), it calls it and pass along the keyword arguments, `exp`.

So, you need to adjust your code:

```py
class TestClass(Function):
    def _latex(self, printer, exp=None):
        m = self.args[0]
        _m = printer.doprint(m)
        base = _m + '(x)'
        if exp is None:
            return base
        return base + "^{%s}" % exp

S = Symbol('S')
expr = TestClass(S)
latex(expr**3)
# out: 'S(x)^{3}'
```